# How do I make image hover work on border - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have designed two borders. One behind the image (black border) and the second on the image (pink border). The image hover is working outside the pink border. But isn't working inside it. How can I make hover work inside the pink border as well?

HTML:

```
<div class="img-border1">
            <img src="https://assets.entrepreneur.com/content/3x2/2000/20191219170611-GettyImages-1152794789.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-border1{
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid;
        width: 20%;
        height: 200px;
    }
   
    .img-border1 img{
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 265px;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        transition: .25s;
        left: 15px;
        top: 15px;
        
    }
    .img-border1 img:hover{
        filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: none;
    }
    .img-border1::after{
        border: 4px solid orchid;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        right: -40px;
        bottom: -40px;
    }
```

Visual Representation at: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/jOMMeaM)

Comment: I guess your problem in a `.img-border1::after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `:hover` to `.img-border1` instead of `img`.

```css
.img-border1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
}

.img-border1 img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 265px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: .25s;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.img-border1:hover img {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: none;
}

.img-border1::after {
  border: 4px solid orchid;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  right: -40px;
  bottom: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-border1">
  <img src="https://assets.entrepreneur.com/content/3x2/2000/20191219170611-GettyImages-1152794789.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: oh right! it's now the border above the image. Thank you so much.